# Displaying large text files on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, text-processing

I need to display large-ish text files (under 10 MB) on mobile device browsers. Downloading the file in chunks isn't currently supported.

What I currently do right now is the following:

1. Download file
2. Put file contents into a `<pre>` tag

The problem with this is that the `<pre>` doesn't do word-wrapping well with the `word-wrap:break-words` CSS. It breaks words (obviously) in unacceptable ways and makes the displayed text unreadable. No word-wrapping isn't an option, because you don't want horizontal scrolling (and mobile Safari simply refuses to spawn horizontal scrollbars on `<pre>` elements)

Transforming the plain text into equivalent HTML and then inserting said HTML into the DOM takes forever (the insertion is the bottleneck here; conversion time is on the order of milliseconds).

Any ideas as to how to display plain text in an acceptable fashion on a mobile device?

#### Edit:

Removed the part about using web workers because it can't do DOM manipulation and at the time, I thought text processing was the bottleneck

Comment: There are numerous options here, but basically you're going to need some way of doing an HTML conversion in chunks. The best way to do that is going to be dependent on how you display the data, and how it's used. Probably you're going to want to come up with a scheme for breaking it into pages.

Comment: Your requirements seem onerous. 10MB of plain text is about 1,500,000 words, which is several days of reading at least. Even 1MB is several hours of reading, which would seem like forever on a mobile device. I think you need a very much more efficient strategy.

Comment: You might want to use a Java applet helper to bypass the browser's limitation in order to partially download the file.

Comment: @RobG I agree the requirements seem onerous for, say, an e-book (_Anna Karenina_ is only on the order of 3 MB in plain text), but not something like a log file. It's true that you can't really Ctrl+F in a page in most mobile browsers today, but that could change in the future.

Comment: @hobberwickey Right now I have implemented a chunking strategy where I insert new text when the user reaches near the bottom of the document but it's not ideal for the reasons above (allowing full-text search of a log file)

Comment: @Jay This is for a mobile browser; it rules out Java applets entirely. And in general, they're a bad idea because of many, many reasons

Comment: probably the easiest, though not the prettiest perhaps, is to use load all the data, but only render what's on the screen. It can be accomplished relatively easy by using strict formatting rules and a monospaced font so you can calculate the size of a substring of your main text. Then you can jump to wherever in the text, calculate the chunk of text that will fit on the screen, and render just that chunk. You can do it with a non-monospaced font to, but it's more a bit more complicated.

Comment: Do you need to use a browser? I googled for "vim for android" and got several hits, maybe you could install a text editor on your mobile device and use that?

Comment: @Paddy3118 No. This is part of a mobile web application that allows you to view text files.

Comment: If it is "something like a log file" then it may be better to summarize and/or triage the log and send the summary instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it was as follows:

```
<pre id='text_preview'>
</pre>
```

Approximate code below.

```
$.get("url/of/text/file.txt", function(response) {
    var fileText = response, pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 105600;
    //first 100 kb of content, assuming 8 bytes/char
    //don't have exact value for this, using approx
    $('#text_preview').text(fileText.slice(0, pageNumber * pageSize);
    window.onscroll = function() {
       //implementation of this left as an exercise for the reader
       if(scrollNearBottom()) {
          pageNumber++;
          $("#text_preview").append(fileText.slice((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize, pageNumber * pageSize);
       }
    }
});
```

Obviously, this won't help my need to find text using Ctrl+F but does satisfy the requirement that I be able to display large e-books.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the document you are showing is a log file...

Tail the file in some fashion, taking, say, only the last 1k lines. Load with javascript and make each line an entry in a list, and use css or javascript to **put a background color on alternating elements**. This makes the line breaks irrelevant without adding a need for horizontal scrolling.

At the top of the document have an **input element whose contents are used to filter the list**. Any time the contents of the input element changes, elements in the list not matching it (as a regex) are hidden and the color banding is re-applied. If you can't display the whole file at once, you can re-request the file based on the contents of the filter box (perhaps with another button press).